# If line contains string, save unspecified number of characters

Tags: python-2.7

I am writing a small script for a client to take the output of event viewer security logs to list the number of times a user connects to a DC server over a week (event viewer is configured to output a .txt file on the first day of the week).

The script I currently have prints out the name and time of the connection, however I would like to add a functionality to record how many times each user connects.

The client has quite frequent turn over of staff, so I would like to not have to edit the script everytime a new user joins or leaves.

Is there a way to save an unspecified number of characters after a specified string?

The string I am trying to record is the username, when the string in question has a format "DOMAIN\USERNAME".

So, for example, if user Michael signs into the Microsoft domain (MICROSOFT\Michael) it will just save Michael into a tally.

Example 1:

Event viewer will throw out about 200,000 of the below a week:

Authentication Package: MICROSOFT_AUTHENTICATION_PACKAGE_V1_0
Logon Account:  Company\Admin
Source Workstation: 
Error Code: 0xC000006A"
Audit Failure   15/01/2018 13:07:36 Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing 4776    Credential Validation   "The computer attempted to validate the credentials for an account.Authentication Package:  MICROSOFT_AUTHENTICATION_PACKAGE_V1_0
Logon Account:  Company\User 1
Source Workstation: 
Error Code: 0xC000006A"
Audit Failure   15/01/2018 13:07:36 Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing 4776    Credential Validation   "The computer attempted to validate the credentials for an account.

I've written a bit of basic code to strip away the unneeded information, the below is a small part of it:

```
    for line in file_name.readlines():
        enter code here if "Logon Account" in line:
            new_file.write(line)
```

Basically, when each line is read, if it the user is not previously recorded, add the user to a dictionary, and when the username is repeated later in the file increase the key by one.

Comment: I'm unclear on what the actual problem is. This might benefit from some code and examples.

Comment: See edit 1. Does it make any more sense to you now?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're stuck on. How to create a dictionary? How to increment dictionary values?

Comment: I'm not stuck on that. What the information I want to retrieve from the above example is just what is after the 'domain\'. So if the line read "Company\User 1" I only want "User 1" to be stored. If it were a fixed length, that would be fine, however, the names range in length from 3 characters to 12 characters in length

Comment: Ah, ok. `fullusername.split('\\')[1]`?

Comment: Thanks. Figured out another way to do it as well by messing around.

    print line[23::]

Answer (score 0):

Use regex for it, example:

```
import re
m = re.search('(?<=domain\\)(.*)', yourstring)
print m.group(1)
```